# Linq query not matching hrefs

Tags: regex, linq, xlink

I'm trying to write out all matches found using a regex with the code below:

```
  var source = "<Content><link><a xlink:href=\"tcm:363-48948\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\">Read more</a></link><links xlink:href=\"tcm:362-65596\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"/></Content>";
  var tridionHref = new Regex("tcm:([^\"]*)");
  var elem = XElement.Parse(source);

  XNamespace xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

  if (tridionHref.IsMatch(elem.ToString()))
  {
      foreach (var Id in elem.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute(xlink + "href") != null))
      {
          Console.WriteLine(Id.Attribute(xlink + "href").Value); //For testing
          Id.Attribute(xlink + "href").Value = Id.Attribute(xlink + "href").Value.Replace("value1", "value2"); //Just to show you an example 
      }
  }
```

My console window outputs `tcm:362-65596` but not `tcm:363-48948`. It looks like the code doesn't see the value of `xlink:href` inside my `<a>` tag as an attribute? Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need to match ALL instances of `tcm:([^\"]*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. I didn't need a regex I just needed to get the `Descendants` instead inside my for loop. `foreach (var Id in elem.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute(xlink + "href") != null))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not looking in the right place. Your `elem.Elements` is looking at the `link` element and the `links` element. Only one of these has the attribute that you are looking for. You'll need to select the elements you want to check more precisely before looking for the right attribute.